# Swift AVPlayer to ear speaker

Tags: swift, avplayer

I've got a simple audio player that works great. I'm playing a remote URL MP3. My code:

```
@IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
        let url = self.productAudio
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.
        player.rate = 1.0;
        player.play()
}
```

But the audio is outputed by the loud speaker. How can I play the audio through the ear speaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer...

I had to modify my Audio Session, and override the port. This is the code before the player code:

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var error: NSError?

    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: &error)
    session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.None, error: &error)
    session.setActive(true, error: &error)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5.0**

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do{
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
            try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print ("\(#file) - \(#function) error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```